# Redux mockStore's expected action is only returning first element of list

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, redux-thunk

```
const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);

const originals = {
    Actions: {}
};
const mocks = {
    Actions: {
        addPasswordResetRequest: spy(() =>{
            return [
                {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST},
                {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_SUCCESS}
            ];
        })
    }
}

//(have functions to mock actions)

...

it('should create an action to request a password reset', (done) => {
    nock('http://localhost:8080/')
    .post('/password-reset-requests')
    .reply(200);
    var email = "test@email.com";
    const expectedActions= [
        {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST},
        {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_SUCCESS}
    ];
    const store = mockStore({}, [
        {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST},
        {type: REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_SUCCESS}
    ], done);
    store.dispatch(Actions.addPasswordResetRequest(email));
    unMockActions();


 });
```

Response I get:

```
Error: Expected [ { type: 'REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST' },
{type: 'REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST_SUCCESS' } ] to equal 
{type: 'REQUEST_ADD_PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST' }
```

When I run this code, I only get the first action returned, not the second one. And it's not a list, it's only one action. I need to test the sequence of the actions, not whether one action is called.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this when trying to test a reducer that had more than one action type in it. With Mocha you can only test 1 action at a time. Ive not tested any 'thunked' action creators yet, but i would expect that the mock action creator would test for the second action and that should be captured in a test for that action creator.